# Knockout array of arrays

Tags: knockout.js

The incomming data is like this `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and sometimes it is like this `[[1,2],[4,5]]`. Here is the HTML.

```
<button data-bind="click: refreshJSON">Test</button>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: array">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: subarray">
            <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">


    var ViewModel = {

        tableModel : ko.observableArray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),

        refreshJSON : function(){
            this.tableModel([[1,2],[4,5]]);
        }

    };

    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);

</script>
```

I'm guessing I have to use `ko.observableArray()` on each of the subarrays however I'm unclear on how to do this, or how to do the `data-binds` in the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Update: Removed the observableArray inside an observableArray bit. Apparently that doesn't work. Just bind your outer collection.

The binding part is fairly easy:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: tableModel">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to add the items individually, just set the `tableModel` directly.  But anyway, the bindings just needed to be corrected.

Comment: Currently, Knockout doesn't work so well with `observableArray` inside of `observableArray` list this. Like Jeff said, you only need the outer observableArray, and just set it to `outerArray`. See this [issue](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/482).

Comment: @JeffMercado: I haven't tried it, but if you have an array inside of an observableArray, will it see removal and additions to the inner array? I would assume not. But I guess (according to Michael) it doesn't work to have an observableArray inside an observableArray anyway.

Comment: To be able to see any changes to any object, you would have to put it inside an observable. If the inner arrays were not made observable, you wouldn't see changes made to them. However since the outer array was made observable, you'd see changes to that. And yes, you _can_ have an observable array within another, it's just that in this case, it probably isn't needed.